# Which approach is best for a 11 independent, 2 dependent variable predictive modeling system?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn, knn

I would guess that this will be best done with machine learning, but I am still fairly new at ML.

I have a system that is 11 independent variables:

```
           'Time1',
           'Y-Radial | Band 1 (in/sec)',
           'Y-Radial | Peak Acceleration (g)',
           'Y-Radial | Peak Velocity (in/s)',
           'X-Axial | RMS Velocity (in/s)',
           'X-Axial | Temperature (F)',
           'X-Axial | Peak Acceleration (g)',
           'X-Axial | Peak Velocity (in/sec)',
           'Y-Radial | RMS Velocity (in/s)',
           'Y-Radial | Temperature (F)',
           'X-Axial | Band 1',
           'Battery Voltage (V)'
```

And two dependent variables:

```
           'Y-Radial | Damage Accumulation',
           'X-Axial | Damage Accumulation'
```

I have two training sets and a test set, we have been looking at linear regression, neural network regression, KNN, and others but are unsure if any of these methods are worth going into for this.

Help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Are your two dependent variables continuous (ie. real numbers) or categorical (like "damage" vs. "no damage")?

Comment: another clarification pls: do you have labels available for your model? (supervised model) Or you do not have any historical/empirical to be used as labels and you need your model to determine patterns on its own? (unsupervised model)

Comment: The two dependents are continuous. It has historical data that can be used to determine patterns. Thank you @Marc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long answer but sharing my thoughts here, to help picking the best approach for your specific problem.

For your use case, since you have a labelled dataset on hand, we are looking at a **supervised** machine learning problem (ruling out *unsupervised* and *reinforcement learning* here).

The two target variables are continuous (not classes/binary), so we need a predictive model based on **regression** and not *classification*.

What is learned is not a decision boundary, so no need for SVM ([Support Vector Machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine)). The model does not learn from probability distributions either, so we can rule out [generative learning algorithms](https://see.stanford.edu/materials/aimlcs229/cs229-notes2.pdf) like GDA or Naive Bayes.

You have only 12 input feature vectors (low dimensionality of the input space), so point to go into [dimensionality reduction techniques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionality_reduction) like PCA or NMF.

You mentioned [kNN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm) in your question. The classification version should obviously been ruled out but the regression flavour of kNN could be used here.
However, that would not be my preferred choice for two reasons: 1) very sensitive to outliers (raw distances calculations), which I suspect should be a significant issue looking at your given features. And 2) kNN needs homogeneous features, with similar scales and weights across features, which also might not match your dataset.

Your model appears to be linear, so no need to go into [non-linear regression techniques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis#Nonlinear_regression).

In the supervised world and linear regression class of algorithms - we are now pretty much down to [multiple linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) and [ANN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network) regression.

At the risk of over-simplifying here, the ANN approach would not be my choice here. For two main reasons: 1) The black box nature of ANN's will not allow you to properly explain the prediction of your two target variables, which is typically a significant issue, not only for your customers but also for yourself if you are an Engineering team - being able to "explain" the inferences, as well as the importance/weight of each input variable into the final prediction is very nice to have (and definitely a strong point of traditional linear regression techniques). 2) ANN are more prone to overfitting than traditional linear regression tools.

Conclusion: I would go for a traditional multiple regression approach.

I see that you are coding in Python. No need for TensorFlow/Keras here then. Scikit-Learn alone should handle it smoothly.

Last element for your decision is which exact technique to pick to implement this multiple linear regression model, in practice.

Simplest way would be to instantiate a simple [LinearRegression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html) regressor class from Scikit-Learn.

However, [XGBoost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XGBoost) is arguably the most powerful tool for this job. That would be my favorite choice. Good news is, it also comes out-of-the-box in Scikit-Learn and fairly straightforward to implement. I would just follow this Python XGBoost tutorial from Kaggle, [here](https://www.kaggle.com/stuarthallows/using-xgboost-with-scikit-learn).

For the sake of completeness - decision trees, bagging, random forests, boosting techniques would also be applicable solutions here but, long story short, **XGBoost** is just superior to all these similar classes of ML techniques.